# How to get the raw printer tray ID

Tags: java, printing, tray

I’m trying to find the printer tray ids of a particular printer. I have searched and found a lot of articles in Java using the `PrintService`, Media and `MediaTray`. Yet, this doesn’t provide a solution for my requirement.  I will get the following output if I run the below code.

```
String printName = "AL-M2010-3D8E02";
AttributeSet aset = new HashAttributeSet();
aset.add(new PrinterName(printName, null));
PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, aset);
for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
    PrintService service = services[i];
    System.out.println(service);
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE;
    Object o = service.getSupportedAttributeValues(Media.class, flavor, null);
    if (o != null && o.getClass().isArray()) {
        for (Media media : (Media[]) o) {
            if (media instanceof MediaTray) {
                System.out.println(media + " ID: " + media.getValue() + "\t" + media.getClass().getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Win32 Printer : AL-M2010-3D8E02

Form-Source ID: 5   sun.print.Win32MediaTray

MP Tray ID: 6   sun.print.Win32MediaTray

Lower Cassette 1 ID: 7  sun.print.Win32MediaTray

Lower Cassette 2 ID: 8  sun.print.Win32MediaTray

Lower Cassette 3 ID: 9  sun.print.Win32MediaTray

Lower Cassette 4 ID: 10 sun.print.Win32MediaTray

If I run the following .net code I would get the following outpt.

```
PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "AL-M2010-3D8E02";

for (int i = 0; i < printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSources.Count; i++)
{
    trayDetails.AppendText(printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSources[i].SourceName + " " + printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSources[i].RawKind.ToString());
    trayDetails.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Automatically Select 15

MP Tray 261

Lower Cassette 1 260

Lower Cassette 2 259

Lower Cassette 3 258

Lower Cassette 4 257

The above is what I want to achieve. I want to get the raw printer ID like 260, 259, 258 and so on through Java instead of getting 7,8,9 and 10. Is this possible in some way?

Answer (score 1):

To your above code just add 3 more lines. All you need is to print winID property from "Win32MediaTray" object.

```
if (o != null && o.getClass().isArray()) {
        for (Media media : (Media[]) o) {
            if (media instanceof MediaTray) {
                System.out.println(media + " ID: " + media.getValue() + "\t" + media.getClass().getName());

                 if(media instanceof sun.print.Win32MediaTray){
                      Win32MediaTray  win32Tray = (Win32MediaTray)media;
                      System.out.println(win32Tray.winID);
                  }

            }
        }
    }
```